# Prepared statements using multiple values

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm looking to improve the security of database access on a website, and the general consensus seems to be to use prepared statements.  I have an idea of how they work, but I want to generalize their use so the only things I need to supply are a query, the parameter types, and values.  However, I haven't found any particularly good resources for this and as a result, I'm sort of lost as to how I should approach this.

Basically, what I want is as follows.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1 = ? AND Column2 = ?";

$array[0] = "string";
$array[1] = 5;
$parameters = "si";

$dbHandler = new mysqli("server", "user", "password", "database");

$stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($parameters, $array);
$stmt->execute();

//Process results
```

I'm aware that this isn't the proper procedure but that's the problem.  What can I do to make this work?  The idea is that the number of variables within `$array` may change, as will the parameter list.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. You say the only things you want to supply are "a query, the parameter types, and values" — that's exactly how prepared statements already work in all cases everywhere.

Comment: The array part is what I don't know about.  The standard use of prepared statements is to list the values like `bind_param("sss", $s1, $s2, $s3);`, but I want to use an array in the place of the three string variables.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you're doing this in `mysqli` — I thought it was PDO, which does just work with arrays from the outset. (If you're just switching and the syntax matters, "use PDO" may be a viable option here.)

Comment: I'm willing to work with PDO, whatever works, honestly.  The primary objective, however, is to avoid SQL injection.  I've read that prepared statements can alleviate this problem but does that also apply to prepared statements through PDO?  I've only ever seen examples with mysqli.

Comment: Have you tried `call_user_func_array()`?

Comment: No, but I've seen it referenced in some of the places where I've looked.  I don't get how to use it though.  Some of the material claims that you need to pass the array by reference or something but not a lot of it made sense.  Most of the examples were extremely convoluted.

Comment: You'd call `call_user_func_array()` passing the function to call (`array($stmt, 'bind_param')`) and the array of arguments. There's no trick to it. PDO definitely supports prepared statements too, if that's more appealing.

Comment: So just to confirm, the resulting line would be something like `$result = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param), $array);`, right?  Will this implementation require 5.6?  The site is currently using 5.4.7 and I want to cover all my bases before I make the final decision regarding whether I should use PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to supply are a query, the parameter types, and values.

Here you go:

```
function mysqli_query_params($mysqli, $query, $params, $types = NULL)
{
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat('s', count($params));
    $statement->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

which can be used exactly the way you described:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1 = ? AND Column2 = ?";
$params = ["string", 5];
$types = "si";
$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "user", "password", "database");

$data = mysqli_query_params($mysqli, $query, $params, $types)->get_result()->fetch_all();
```

Note that most of time you can avoid setting types explicitly and let them be mound as strings by default.

However, PDO indeed is way more usable than raw mysqli, and you better use it. You may learn it from [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

P.S. You need PHP  >=5.6 and mysqlnd installed for this code to run. Otherwise the amount of code will be increased tenfold. That's another reason to use PDO.

Comment: You have to use PHP 5.6+